# Allegrograph Geospatial Prolog Queries

Tags: prolog, geospatial, semantic-web, allegrograph

I have some triples that represent the locations of several cities.  I want to be able to fire off a Prolog query like

```
(select (?x ?y ?dist) 
(q- ?x !exns:geolocation ?locx)
(q- ?y !exns:geolocation ?locy)
(geo-distance ?locx ?locy ?dist))
```

but I get this error:

`Server returned 400: attempt to call '#:geo-distance/3' which is an undefined function.`

I'd like to understand how to use the geospatial reasoning methods like `geo-distance` (I assumed it was built-in because they use it [here](http://data.semanticweb.org/pdfs/iswc/2009/industry/iswc_industry_02.pdf).  Is this not true though?) in a Prolog query, because this is currently a mystery to me and I haven't found any good examples for doing this.

I am using the Python API, BTW, and in the [Python API tutorial](http://www.franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/current/python-tutorial/python-tutorial-40.html#Geospatial%20Search) they use the `getStatements` method to retrieve triples within a circle of some radius.  I want to be able to do this kind of thing in a Prolog query, and from the Python API, not from AllegroCL--I'd like to build web apps and I don't know how to do that in AllegroCL, but I do know how in Python.

Comment: It turns out geo-distance is not a built-in function, but it can be defined in AllegroCL like this: `(<-- (geo-distance ?point1 ?point2 ?dist)
      (lisp ?dist (let (lon1 lat1 lon2 lat2)
     (setf (values lon1 lat1) (upi->longitude-latitude ?point1))
     (setf (values lon2 lat2) (upi->longitude-latitude ?point2))
     (haversine-miles lon1 lat1 lon2 lat2))))
`

However, this definition does not work using addRules from the Python API because it won't let you do the (lisp ) escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to make geospatial Prolog queries from the Python API.  You have to use the Allegro Common Lisp IDE to do this.

**EDIT:**  Not So!

With AllegroGraph 4.6 you can do this!  The problem was that I was using AllegroGraph 3.3, so I'm an idiot.

Here's a Prolog rule that works from the Python API using AllegroGraph 4.6:

```
(<-- (geo-distance ?point1 ?point2 ?dist)
      (lisp ?dist (let (lon1 lat1 lon2 lat2)
           (setf (values lon1 lat1) (upi->longitude-latitude ?point1))
           (setf (values lon2 lat2) (upi->longitude-latitude ?point2))
           (haversine-miles lon1 lat1 lon2 lat2))))
```

Special thanks to the folks at Franz Allegro support for helping me!